# Is this Parameter Sniffing?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2019, performance-tuning

I have a particular stored procedure that takes 1 parameter.

This proc is executed once a day with the **same parameter** value everyday. The row count is also the same with each run of the proc.

Day 1 - Runs for 10 minutes.

Day 2 - Runs for 8 hours.

Each run produces the exact same query plan.

In an attempt to remedy this, I added **OPTION (RECOMPILE)** to the problematic statement and it seems to have fixed it. It's been 5 days and each run has been 10 minutes.

My understanding of bad parameter sniffing is when the cached query plan is not optimal for certain parameter values.

So, how do I actually define this problem?

What would cause this drastic change in runtimes if the query plan is exactly the same and the parameter value is the same?

Edit:
Query Store is enabled on the database. Using this, I was able to determine that the query plans are identical between good and bad runs.

This is the part of the query plan that does the bulk of the work.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: which SQL Server version you have ?

Comment: SQL Server 2019

Comment: "that does the bulk of the work" is probably not true, estimates involving XML or other Table Functions are notoriously inaccurate. Please show the *full* query, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: This is not really a parameter sniffing issue when it's always the same value and data statistics. If the query plans are truly identical, then your issue is likely something external, causing one run to wait longer than another. It could be hardware contention, or it could be a sign of failing hardware, or it could be something happening external to the SQL Server that the query is waiting on (depending on what the query does), etc. But no way to say without seeing the good and bad run query plans which you should upload and link in your Post, as Charlieface mentioned.

Comment: check Waits of your stored procedure. Maybe it is being blocked by something, or experiencing any other wait type

Comment: If you're not seeing actual changes in the execution plans, then it is not parameter sniffing. However, do you see two plans, but they have similar shapes so you think they are identical? Run them through the compare plans utility in SSMS or in Plan Explorer and see if there are differences.

Comment: I ran the XML of the plans through a compare tool and they're identical

Comment: It could still be the data that's causing the problem: for example an entire branch of the query plan not being used sometimes. Can we have the Actual as opposed to Estimated plans, please share as mentioned via PasteThePlan, also some table structures (with indexes) and sample data.

Comment: @GrantFritchey  but also notice that OPTION (RECOMPILE) fix the problem.

Comment: @kumarharsh For a recompile hint to fix the problem, it certainly suggests that there would be more than one plan. Yet, they say there isn't. That seems unlikely but we're not there, so we're dependent on the evidence provided.

Answer (score 0):

If the query plan really doesn't change then it's not a parameter sniffing issue.  Some more information is needed to diagnose this issue though.  Maybe there is a subtle difference in the query plans that is not immediately obvious. If the query has scalar functions, these execute in their own context with their own associated query plans.  We can only make guesses at this point though.

What would be useful would be to capture what the query is doing at various points in its execution.  Community scripts like sp_whoisactive, and sp_BlitzWho are useful here.  You can see the statement currently executing.  The current wait type and session level wait information are useful for diagnosing the problem.

Also, consider a monitoring tool – I created an open-source tool [DBA Dash](https://dbadash.com/).  This will automatically capture the running query information (similar to sp_whoisactive or sp_BlitzWho).  If you had the tool running, you could go back in time and work out exactly why your query was slow 6 days ago.  It will help if the problem re-occurs while you are not around to troubleshoot.